# In python, How to divide multivariate Gaussian distributions to separate Gaussians?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute the confidence interval of my data. I plot their histogram. I found that it may follow  a multivariate normal distribution.

1. How to divide multivariate Gaussian distributions to separate 
   Gaussians?? I think that it is possible to create clusters where every 
   cluster presents one gaussian. But I don't know how to do that.
2. I want to extract the parameters of every Gaussian? sigma, mean
3. I don't know how to compute the whole confidence interval of them: In general, I know that when computing the confidence interval for one gaussian distribution, I use :

   sigma=1
   mean=0
   ci = scipy.stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=mean, scale=sigma)
   print(ci)
   But sigma, mean is unique for every gaussian.
4. What is the job of Loglikelihood of Multivariate Normal Distribution ?  Why to do such test?

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from scipy.misc import factorial
   import seaborn as sns
   from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

   sns.set_style('darkgrid')
   data= [65.4243243046107, 65.45963969900394, 65.28583696534378, 65.64727793480667,......]
   ```

   sns.distplot(data, kde=True)
   plt.show()

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what a multivariate Gaussian is. Try reading this:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Your data is not multivariate. It is univariate.

What you have here is perhaps, multiple distributions being combined, each with their own sigma and mu.

Try starting here:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mixture_distribution

Comment: Teghan, Yes you are right.  could I  edit my question ?